# Timeout to load ArcGIS Server hosted layers

Tags: arcgis-server

I'm sharing a map and a geoprocessing service in ArcGIS Server. I configured the CMV(Configurable Map viewer) with the rest URLs to consume them. I deployed the CMV in a IIS server, then call the CMV in a iframe in my asp.net MVC 5 application.

When I'm running the CMV in local, the layers and the geoprocessing services are well loaded so usable. However when I'm running from my application it never loads and it gives me a timeout error.

I googled a bit and I found that I have to add this line in the web.config file, so the timeout would be extended :

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="21600" />
```

Yet nothing changes and the layers are not added to the map.
Do you know what may cause this  issue right here?

Comment: I'd open the browser developer tools and check the console. Are you getting any errors from the app or any errors from the service? Its probably not a timeout issue. It could be a CORS or other security related issue which appears like a timeout problem.

Comment: Yeah it is, I checked in an other server and every thing was fine. Actually the port from where I'm listening to arcgis api is closed so I bet that's the origin of this behaviour. I'm wainting for the security engineer to get it done so I can confirm and aswer my post.